# How to change css color scheme by applying hue change co all colors in css file

Tags: css, shell, hue

I have a css file and i want automatically create few color variations of the file, using something like "colorize" in GIMP to shift hue of template.

I found something that does exacly what i want: http://adityabhandari.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/ColorChanger.html 
but it not support `rgba()` notation i often use.

I'm linux user so maybe some tricky shell script with regex will do, problem is i really suck at regex.

If you post `php/python/awk` solution I'm smart enough to use it to.

Answer (score 0):

**[LESS.css](http://lesscss.org/#-color-functions)**

It adds a number of convenience methods to CSS, including hex/rgba arithmetic, and will compile to 'native' CSS with the command line utility, which you will find intuitive.

```
spin(#BEFBA, 10);   // return a color with a 10 degree larger in hue than #BEFBA
@color: #BEFBA;     // just a variable
spin(@color, -10);  // return a color with a 10 degree smaller in hue than @color

// applied to css class:
.myStyle{
    background-color: spin( @color, 10 );  
}
```